# Webpage is not available in Magento installation

Tags: magento-1.8, wamp, localhost

I'm trying install Magento in my localhost, but I'm getting the message "This webpage is not available". I've installed WAMP and it works fine. Then, I extracted magento to "www" folder of WAMP. I'm using Windows 8.1, Wamp 2.2 and Magento 1.8.1.

Comment: is your other projects from the www is running properly check that ?

Comment: I don't have other projects in Wamp. My other projects is in a remote server. But I thought about it before and created a test folder and put a simple php file and it works fine.

Comment: provide url that you are tried? provide the directory structure starts from `www`? check for the permission of magento directory. Most importantly, create a `test.php` inside `www` directory and put `<?php echo phpinfo();` there and then load `localhost/test.php`. check it loading properly

Comment: I tried several urls: localhost/magento, www.localhost.com/magento and localhost.com/magento.

Comment: I created the file test.php and it loads fine. The structure of www:
.folder
..index.php
.magento
..magento files
.index.php
.test.php
.testmysql.php
The magento directory is read-only.

Comment: Clarifying the structure of www:  /folder
/folder/index.php 
/magento 
/magento/magento_files 
/index.php 
/test.php 
/testmysql.php

Comment: Anyone have some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem was the version of Wamp. This version of Magento isn't compatible with this version of Wamp. Then, I only made the downgrade to Wamp 2.1 and all works fine now.